# After pandas .agg the histogram produced is taking a count of each record instead of taking the value within the column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Based on the data below I want to create a histogram. How can I do this? The code below is reading the data as a count of 1 for each record instead of taking the value from patient_unique_count

```
df5=df.groupby(["PANDEMIC","PATIENT_AGE_GRP"]).agg(
    {"PATIENT_ID": pd.Series.nunique}).rename(columns={'PATIENT_ID':'PATIENT_UNIQUE_COUNT'})
sns.histplot(x='PATIENT_AGE_GRP', data=df5, kde=True, hue='PANDEMIC')
plt.show()
```

```
                          PATIENT_UNIQUE_COUNT
PANDEMIC PATIENT_AGE_GRP                      
AFTER    15-19                              14
         20-24                              21
         25-29                              58
         30-34                              90
         35-39                             156
         40-44                             194
         45-49                             266
         50-54                             369
         55-59                             535
         60-64                             660
         65-69                             829
         70-74                             823
         75-79                             713
         80-84                             657
         85-89                             576
         90+                               595
         <1                                  1
         NA                                  5
BEFORE   15-19                              13
         20-24                              14
         25-29                              41
         30-34                              56
         35-39                             144
         40-44                             179
         45-49                             279
         50-54                             466
         55-59                             758
         60-64                             873
         65-69                             929
         70-74                             890
         75-79                             860
         80-84                             789
         85-89                             726
         90+                               757
         NA                                 11
```

The code is reading the data as a count of 1 for each record instead of taking the value from patient_unique_count. I would also like the histograms to be side by side for before and after pandemic flag.

Comment: Maybe you want to create a bar plot? Or a count plot starting from the original dataframe? E.g. `sns.countplot(df, x="PANDEMIC", hue="PATIENT_AGE_GRP")`

Comment: the issue with this is that I need the unique count of PATIENT_ID grouped by PANDEMIC